# Add default value to QCombobox Binded with QSqlQueryModel

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

My problem is i want database data plus a default value in QComboBox. When i use
QStringList by each call of function i have repetitive items. Here is the updateComboBox function :

```
void MainWindow::updCombo(){


QSqlQuery * qry1 = new QSqlQuery(mydb);
qry1->prepare("select DISTINCT  Grp from Poems");
qry1->exec();
QStringList strList;
while(qry1->next()) {

    if(!strList.contains(qry1->value(0).toString()))
    {
        qDebug()<< qry1->value(0).toString();
        strList->append(qry1->value(0).toString());
    }

}

ui->comboBox->addItems(strList);
```

}

Comment: What is the default value? 
still you continue to abuse dynamic memory. what is the problem?

Comment: When i use QSqlQueryModel and bind it to QComboBox it wont allow me to have extrnal value like " All ".Please explain about abusing dynamic memory. Is it possible dynamically add to QSqlQueryModel object ?

Comment: Why do you use `QSqlQuery *qry1 = new QSqlQuery(mydb);` instead of `QSqlQuery qry1(mydb)`?

Comment: Ok i get it. I  understood i should avoid that as possible as.

Comment: When creating a pointer you have the responsibility to remove it from memory, that you should know, is basic C++. That is the advantage of C++ that brings a great responsibility.

Comment: Is it possible dynamically add to QSqlQueryModel object ?

Comment: it depends on where you created it, is it a member of the class? If it is not, you must use a pointer to extend its scope.

Comment: Could you answer my question to avoid repetitive addition in QComboBox?

Comment: your method is correct but you should clean the combobox before.

Comment: some news??????